# Is there a reason for mapping a network drive that was also being remotely accessed through Network Sharing by the same PC?

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-drive, sharing, mapped-drive

Is there a connection/reason for mapping a network drive and Network Sharing that same PC?  Both PCs run Windows 10 Pro.  Because a PC that has been remotely accessing mine, through Network Sharing and Remote Desktop, has mapped the network drive of my PC also. What would the reason be for this?

Comment: Some programs may be written in ways or with code libraries that do not support UNC pathnames (`\\server\resource`), and require "classical" drive/directory pathnames (`C:\path\to\file`). To accommodate such programs, one would have to map a drive letter to the connected UNC resource.

Comment: Even using Windows 10 Remote Desktop? what would be the point? The reason? Does it make future remote access easier/quicker?

Comment: (1) You didn't mention Remote Desktop in your question. (2) Remote Desktop essentially turns the remote computer into a keyboard and screen to your computer. That's not "network sharing". If the other computer wants to run programs on itself, but access data that is stored on your computer, that would use network sharing, and the programs being used may be the type of program that I was referring to in my first comment.

Comment: My error sorry. Both Remote Desktop and Network Sharing have been used to access mine. Am I correct in thinking that mapping my network drive basically puts it in the remote PC’s drive?

Comment: It doesn't put anything on the remote computer; it merely establishes a local legacy-style alias to the network resource - that is, if I map `Q:` to `\\yourcomputer\somefolder`, then a program running on my computer that doesn't understand UNC pathnames can still access `\\yourcomputer\somefolder\thatfile` as `Q:\thatfile`. The file is still on yourcomputer, not mine, but it's accessible _as though_ it were on mine.

Comment: Got you. I sort of guessed as much but didn’t understand the how. Anyway of stopping this breach? Or now I have disabled Remote Desktop and Network Sharing on my PC, does that mean my files are no longer visible on the ‘other PC’s’ drive?

Comment: If you have disabled network sharing and remote desktop, your resources should not be accessible to the other PC. I would not use the term "breach" unless the original sharing was unauthorized.

Comment: It was unauthorised and I am still at a loss as to how they gained access to enable not on my PC. In the middle of changing all passwords etc now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123342/discussion-between-vesper007-and-jeff-zeitlin).